# i have list items. how to read them all by selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, listitem

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <ul>
        <li>Service User Number must be 6 characters</li>
        <li>PSL ID is required</li>
        <li>>Bank Account Id (was Credit AccID) is required</li>
        <li>Account Name is required</li>
        <li>Sort Code is required</li>
        <li>Account Number is required</li>
        <li>Bank Statement Narrative is required</li>
        <li>Company Name is required</li>
        <li>Contact Name is required</li>
        <li>Email Address is required</li>
        <li>Customer Services Phone Number is required</li>
        <li>Phone Number is required</li>
        <li>Address is required</li>
        <li>Reference Number Prefix is required</li>
        <li>Report Email Address is required</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i want to read all the list and get their values of it. is someone help me as quick as possible. as selenium doesnt recognize unordered tag as it doesnt have name and id anything.....please help..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like this:

```
public void test() {
    WebElement ul = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.validation-summary-errors ul"));

    List<WebElement> lis = ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

    for (WebElement li : lis) {
        // do something with li.getText();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do it in two steps? We can find the li in one selector;

```
public void test() {
WebElement lis = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.validation-summary-errors ul>li"));

for (WebElement li : lis) {
    // do something with li.getText();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

@sircapsalot's answer is good, but I would change the first CSS selector to address OP's requirement "selenium doesnt recognize unordered tag as it doesnt have name and id anything"

```
public void test() {
    WebElement ul = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.validation-summary-errors ul"));

    List<WebElement> lis = ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

    for (WebElement li : lis) {
        // do something with li.getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: the HTML was not fully available at the time of my answer ;)  I'll fix that now.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If your SVG data looks like this :

`<div id="content-data" class="col-md-12" style="height:666px;">`
`<svg id="pie-draw-488172" width="492" height="616"><g transform="translate(226,318)">`
`<text id="pie-text" cursor="default" y="-226" x="241">Compute (227,311)</text>`
`<text id="pie-text" cursor="default" y="-211" x="241">Database (98,005)</text>`
`<text id="pie-text" cursor="default" y="-196" x="241">Storage&amp;Content Delivery (69,436)</text>`
`<text id="pie-text" cursor="default" y="-181" x="241">Networking (30,874)</text>`
`<text id="pie-text" cursor="default" y="-166" x="241">Other (11,273)</text>`

`</svg></div>`

then use this

`public List<IWebElement> content_data = new List<IWebElement>();`
 `content_data = driver.FindElement(By.Id("content-data")).FindElements(By.TagName("text")).ToList();`

Comment: The question is about getting data from `<li>`s, not an SVG.